# AppendChild to document.createDocumentFragment

Tags: javascript

I'm having the following code where i'm trying to append a nested html component to a html element

```
var docFrag = document.createDocumentFragment();
var count = 0;

arr.map(function(obj){
    count++;
    var title = obj.title;
    var codeAttr = obj.code;
    var htmlComponent = "<div class='line_h'><div class='floatRadio'><label for='radio_"+count+"'><input name='radio' value='"+codeAttr+"' id='radio_"+count+"' checked='checked' type='radio' class='inputRadio' /><span class='fld_lbl'>"+title+"</span></label></div></div>";

    console.log(htmlComponent);
    docFrag.appendChild(htmlComponent);
})
```

It is iterating through an array of objects from where i get the content to add into the `htmlComponent`. However when executing `docFrag.appendChild(htmlComponent)` it returns an error:

> **Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.**

Indeed i'm passing a string... how may i build a nested html component and push it to `docFrag` ?

Comment: I just want to point out, you can remove your `count` variable entirely and remove the `for` and `id` attributes. Since the `<input>` is *inside* the `<label>`, there's no need to specify belonging to it.

Comment: That's not the way [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is meant to be used. For you problem: build the complete string and then use [`Element.insertAdjacentHTML()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)

Comment: @Andreas. allright - what's wrong with this implementation here of arr.prototype.map ? Then i'm using createDocumentFragment to store the htmlComponents created during iteration that then i'll insert in my DOM tree

Comment: "_The `map()` method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in this array._". The method is used to transform values of an array. This should be a plain old loop or at least [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Answer (score 0):

You must convert first your string to Nodes.
Use this function:

```
function htmlToNodes(html, elementsOnly){
  if(typeof html != 'string') throw new Error('Argument must be a string');
  const template = document.createElement('template');
  template.innerHTML = html.trim();
  return elementsOnly ? template.content.children : template.content.childNodes;
}
```

and then replace `docFrag.appendChild(htmlComponent);` by:

```
  htmlToNodes(htmlComponent).forEach((n)=>{
    docFrag.appendChild(n);
  };
```